# Insert Data In Oracle DataBase

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0, servlet-listeners

//in context listener

```
Statement stmt;
try {
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl","abc", "abc");
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("stmt", stmt);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
} catch (SQLException e) {
}
```

//in Servlet page

```
try {
  Statement stmts=(Statement) getServletContext().getAttribute("stmt");
  stmts.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO COMPANYS values(1,'ahmed',5,'t012','t345','email@eamil','adressadress')");
  System.out.println("connection succeed");
} catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println("connection fail");
}
```

in Servlet page "try code" is execute and "connection succeed" is appearing but in oracle database there is no data inserted >> why???

Comment: Check what value is being returned by stmts.executeUpdate, if its 1 => value was inserted , if 0 => statement didnt succeed

Comment: Did you forget to close your statements and connections?

Comment: it is necessary to close stats and connectio?? i plane to make connection starts when application start and close when application close

Comment: Then simply call `conn.commit();` that doesn't require connection to be closed.

Comment: but in the servelt page there no conn

Comment: con is only in context listener

Answer (score 0):

use con.setAutoCommit(false); after conn has created. Once the transaction completes i.e.,after executeUpdate(...) call con.commit();  It will solve your issue if their are no errors displayed on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try it again with below steps

- Set auto commit as false
- Commit after updating the record to make it persisted in the database
- Rollback if there is any exception while inserting the record
- **Don't** forget to clean-up the environment such as ResultSet, Statement etc.
- Code in finally block to close the resources
- **Don't** keep connection opened for long time.

---

Must read

- [Is it mandatory to close all  ResultSets, Statements and Connections?](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/jdbc-interview-questions/)
- [Java Tutorial - Using Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#release_savepoints)

Find a sample code [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/commit-rollback.htm) with detailed inline comments.